# Pop up menu on click of the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a functionality, where on click of the button, i need to slide up a menu and at the same time on move out of the button or of the popup menu, the menu has to be closed(slideDown).

I have multiple buttons in the page, which contains the menu, so on moving to another button on clicking menu will be opend or  moving out to some other elements in DOM also i need to close the Menu.

Please suggest.

Comment: What have you done so far? - Searched the web for slide menu_?

Comment: Untill now i had set the postion for the popUp menu and slideToggled it. When focusing out to the next button, the menu is closing properly and also on hovering out of the menu, i hiding it. Now the problem is when i move the mouse pointer out of the button, the menu does not hide.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to create a menu and a button that will show and hide from this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){

 if( $(this).text()=="Open")
 {
     $(this).text("Hide");
 }
 else
 {
    $(this).text("Open");
  }
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>

<style> 
#panel,#flip
{
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="flip">Open</button>

<div id="panel">Menu!</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS and Jquery you can set menu css to

```
display:none
```

then just

```
display:block
```

it when button is clicked. or you can also use 
[Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)